# Override controller functions in directive is a good idea?

Tags: angularjs

I have a generic functionality implemented inside a controller. When i write a directive is it good idea to extend those controller functions inside the directive ?

Like in below implementation inside the link function.

```
var superCancel = scope.cancel;
// Overriding the cancel function from the controller
scope.cancel = function() {
  if(element.hasClass('ng-dirty')){
         element.removeClass("ng-dirty");
  }
  // Calling controller cancel
  superCancel();
};
```

Comment: If you talk about generic functionality, then it will be inside `service` or `factory`.

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea, as it introduces an impilicit change of the component's behavior - which is, in general, not a good thing. Then again, ain't this question subjective by definition?

Comment: @raina77ow, I wanted to know this from design perspective. Also, if there is any other way i can achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your directive `html` is coming **inside** the controller in `html` then you can use `$parent` instead of rewriting

in directive:

```
$scope.$parent.cancel(); // only if controller coming as parent
```

If the **controller is not coming as parent** it's better to use a `service` or `factory` to implement that

[Read here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services) for more

Answer (score 0):

It is better to have the directive use an attribute to set a parent scope value.

For example:

JS

```
app.directive("setModelApi", function() {
    return {
        require: "ngModel",
        link: function(scope,elem,attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            scope.$eval(attrs.setModelApi, {$api: ngModelCtrl})
        }
    }
});
```

In the above example, the `setModelApi` directive evaluates the Angular Expression defined by the `set-model-api` attribute with `$api` exposing the `ngModelController`.

HTML

```
<input ng-model="x" set-model-api="xmodel=$api">

<button ng-click="xmodel.$setPristine()">Set Pristine</button>
```

The `setModelApi` directive sets the `xmodel` scope variable to the `ng-model-controller` API.

The button invokes the `$setPristine` method of the `ng-model-controller` API.

From the Docs:

> ### $setPristine();
>
> Sets the control to its pristine state.
>
> This method can be called to remove the `ng-dirty` class and set the control to its pristine state (`ng-pristine` class). A model is considered to be pristine when the control has not been changed from when first compiled.

-- [AngularJS ngModelController API Reference -- $setPristine](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$setPristine)

By using an HTML directive attribute to define the scope variable to which the API attaches, different inputs can use the directive and the connections are exposed in the HTML.

The [DEMO on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u73t52tr/)